# WooCommerce wc_update_product_stock stores number as decimal in database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

When I use this function

```
wc_update_product_stock();
```

to set product stock it always saves the numeric value as float in my database.

As far as I know this function accepts three parameters

```
wc_update_product_stock(  $product,  $stock_quantity, $operation );
```

But when I use it like this

```
wc_update_product_stock( 2319 , 5 , 'set');
```

It stores the value of 5 as 5.000000 and this happens to any other numeric value I tried to use.
[image: number 5 stored as 5.000000 in database]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the function that updates the product stock - It uses `%f` as stock quantity - So its `treated as float` - [more details](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/548ce2bb76b8feee350056d0)

```
public function update_product_stock( $product_id_with_stock, $stock_quantity = null, $operation = 'set' ) {
        global $wpdb;
        add_post_meta( $product_id_with_stock, '_stock', 0, true );

        // Update stock in DB directly.
        switch ( $operation ) {
            case 'increase':
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.VIP.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery
                $wpdb->query(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "UPDATE {$wpdb->postmeta} SET meta_value = meta_value + %f WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key='_stock'",
                        $stock_quantity,
                        $product_id_with_stock
                    )
                );
                break;
            case 'decrease':
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.VIP.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery
                $wpdb->query(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "UPDATE {$wpdb->postmeta} SET meta_value = meta_value - %f WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key='_stock'",
                        $stock_quantity,
                        $product_id_with_stock
                    )
                );
                break;
            default:
                // phpcs:ignore WordPress.VIP.DirectDatabaseQuery.DirectQuery
                $wpdb->query(
                    $wpdb->prepare(
                        "UPDATE {$wpdb->postmeta} SET meta_value = %f WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key='_stock'",
                        $stock_quantity,
                        $product_id_with_stock
                    )
                );
                break;
        }

        wp_cache_delete( $product_id_with_stock, 'post_meta' );
    }
```

For updating directly as Integer ( as it is ) - use this function `update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', 15);`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand why it is stored as float now but then there must be another function used on product edit pages because when I try to set the stock using the product edit stock module it stores numeric value normally. Do I have to write my own reliable function to update stock count properly? I couldn't find another function that can actually update stock count and stock status respectively.

Comment: In that case You use update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', 15);
It will directly update as integer

Comment: In that case I will have to build another function to update stock_status respectively. That's the main reason why I chose wc_update_product_stock, because it handles the stock status update automatically. Can't understand why a function explicitly built to update stock number (which is always whole) uses %f to store the value in database. Makes no sense to me. Anyway I am accepting your answer because it answered my question. I will keep looking for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it could help someone,

If you use `wc_update_product_stock()` with the third param `$operation` as `set` it will save the value as float, indeed.

Now, if you use the `$operation` param as `increase` or `decrease` it will save it as integer. In that case, you just have to pay attention to the second parameter `$stock_quantity`, because it will either increase or decrease the stock and not set it.

Comment: This explains why all the values stored by Woocommerce are stored as integers. Woocommerce must be using `increase` / `decrease` internally.