# WooCommerce why update_product_stock uses float to store the stock in database

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This is a sequel to my previous question [WooCommerce wc_update_product_stock stores number as decimal in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179909/woocommerce-wc-update-product-stock-stores-number-as-decimal-in-database/55180305?noredirect=1#comment97099115_55180305)

User called [mujuonly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1117368/mujuonly) pointed out that

```
wc_update_product_stock()
```

Uses another function called

```
update_product_stock()
```

And in this function you can find the catch. It uses **$wpdb->query** to store the stock value in database as a **FLOAT!!!**.

```
$wpdb->query(
$wpdb->prepare(
    "UPDATE {$wpdb->postmeta} SET meta_value = %f 
    WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key='_stock'",
    $stock_quantity,
    $product_id_with_stock
)
```

);

Now. Can anyone explain, why a function used to store data that is always a whole number casts this value to float?

Comment: After seeing your original question, I became curious about this as well. Digging around in the [changelog](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt#L2407), I found that version 2.2.7 introduced a tweak to allow for non-integer stock quantities. So, there must be some situation in which non-integer stock quantities are needed. I'm really looking forward to finding out more about what those situations would be.

Comment: I am definitely looking for an answer. WooCommerce actually filters those float values back to integers when you use $product->get_stock_quantity(). Currently building some sophisticated $wpdb-> query and found these floats stored in _stock meta fields during query testing.

Comment: I couldn't find out why yet, but if you use the `$operation` param from `wc_update_product_stock()` as `increase` or `decrease` it will save it as integer.